# WPF: Placing a textbox randomly on a canvas

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dynamic, canvas, controls

I have a canvas of sorts derived from a 'Panel' used for custom drawing of lines and other geometries, all from VB code. I got this approach from a book and I'm not sure it's the best approach. The drawing part works so far for me.

But what I need is to put a textbox control on the control containing text which can be edited by the user. The textbox needs to be placed at coordinates determined dynamically and later deleted. There will probably be other controls handled so.

The following code does nothing:

```
    tb = New TextBox()
    tb.Text = "How now brown cow?"
    tb.BorderThickness = New Thickness(3)
    tb.BorderBrush = Brushes.CadetBlue
    drawingSurface.Children.Add(tb)
```

This is the definition of my DrawingCanvas:

```
    Public Class DrawingCanvas
   Inherits Panel

    Private visuals As New List(Of Visual)()
    Private hits As New List(Of DrawingVisual)()

   Protected Overrides Function GetVisualChild(ByVal index As Integer) As Visual
      Return visuals(index)
   End Function
   Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property VisualChildrenCount() As Integer
      Get
         Return visuals.Count
      End Get
   End Property

   Public Sub AddVisual(ByVal visual As Visual)
      visuals.Add(visual)
        MyBase.AddVisualChild(visual)
      MyBase.AddLogicalChild(visual)
   End Sub

   Public Sub DeleteVisual(ByVal visual As Visual)
      visuals.Remove(visual)
        MyBase.RemoveVisualChild(visual)
      MyBase.RemoveLogicalChild(visual)
   End Sub

   Public Function GetVisual(ByVal point As Point) As DrawingVisual
      Dim hitResult As HitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Me, point)
      Return TryCast(hitResult.VisualHit, DrawingVisual)
   End Function

    Public Function GetVisuals(ByVal region As Geometry) As List(Of DrawingVisual)
        hits.Clear()
        Dim parameters As New GeometryHitTestParameters(region)
        Dim callback As New HitTestResultCallback(AddressOf Me.HitTestCallback)
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Me, Nothing, callback, parameters)
        Return hits
    End Function

   Private Function HitTestCallback(ByVal result As HitTestResult) As HitTestResultBehavior
      Dim geometryResult As GeometryHitTestResult = CType(result, GeometryHitTestResult)
      Dim visual As DrawingVisual = TryCast(result.VisualHit, DrawingVisual)
      If visual IsNot Nothing AndAlso geometryResult.IntersectionDetail = IntersectionDetail.FullyInside Then
            hits.Add(visual)
            MsgBox("Ouch")
      End If
      Return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue
   End Function
End Class
```

Here is the XAML. I added a textbox to the DrawingCanvas just to see if something appears. Nothing did. In fact, I want to do this in code, not XAML. I thought I could hide or move it around dynamically.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Music"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="539" Width="892">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="MainMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25">
            <MenuItem Name="File" Header="File">
                <MenuItem Name="Open" Header="Bla bla..."/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <local:DrawingCanvas DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="drawingSurface" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <TextBox Height="0" Name="TextBox1" Width="45" Text="How now brown cow?" />
        </local:DrawingCanvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Thanks for helping a nooby. A solution would be very useful for me. This was easy with windows forms, but I need the drawing speed of WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit off here. In WPF you have a control called Canvas. I would suggest you use that instead of your own "DrawingCanvas", which I can't get to work btw. :(  (For some reason I cant create code blocks so if someone can edit it I would be pleased)

Anyhow,

```
<local:DrawingCanvas DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="drawingSurface" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
   <TextBox Height="0" Name="TextBox1" Width="45" Text="How now brown cow?" />
</local:DrawingCanvas>
```

Turns into:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="drawingSurface">

 </Canvas>
```

And then to add a textbox just do as your current code:

```
Dim tb as New TextBox 
drawingSurface.Children.Add(tb)
```

This should give you what you need.

Heres the code for adding a rectangle to your canvas.

```
Private Sub DrawBackground()
    Dim Rect As New Rectangle()
    Rect.Height = 50
    Rect.Width = 50
    Rect.Fill = Brushes.Cornsilk
    drawingSurface.SetTop(Rect, 30)
    drawingSurface.SetLeft(Rect, 100)
    drawingSurface.Children.Add(Rect)
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't show the code that uses the DrawingCanvas.  Private Sub DrawBackground()
  Using dc As DrawingContext = visBackground.RenderOpen()
   Dim brush As Brush = Brushes.Cornsilk
   Dim drawingPen As Pen = New Pen(Brushes.Cornsilk, 1)
   dc.DrawRectangle(brush, drawingPen, New Rect(0, 0, dblScreenWidth, dblScreenHeight))
  End Using
  drawingSurface.AddVisual(visBackground)
 End Sub

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are after. But I added code that displays how to add stuff to your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another answer that might be more in the line of what you are looking for. This is a class that inherits from Canvas that will allow you to draw stuff in the same way as say you do in your comment.

I also creates a textbox on a random location when it is created.

```
Public Class DrawingCanvas
    Inherits Canvas
    Public RandomTextBox As New TextBox
    Protected Overrides Sub OnRender(dc As System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext)
        Dim brush As Brush = Brushes.Black
        Dim drawingPen As Pen = New Pen(Brushes.Green, 3)
        dc.DrawRectangle(brush, drawingPen, New Rect(5, 5, Me.ActualWidth - 5, Me.ActualHeight - 5))
        RandomTextBox.Text = "Herpdiderp"
        If Not Me.Children.Contains(RandomTextBox) Then
            Dim r As New Random()
            RandomTextBox.Height = 23
            RandomTextBox.Width = 100
            Me.SetTop(RandomTextBox, r.Next(0, Me.ActualHeight - RandomTextBox.Height))
            Me.SetLeft(RandomTextBox, r.Next(0, Me.ActualWidth - RandomTextBox.Width))
            Me.Children.Add(RandomTextBox)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not replying. Been busy with other things and travelling. It might be a bit early to start asking questions like this. I still like the original Wozzeck at this stage.

Comment: (Good thing I'm not a barber.) Using Canvas as a base class works fine. I had to replace "Me" with "Canvas", which makes no sense to me: "Me" is an actual instance and "Canvas" is just a class. But the debugger told me that I accessed "a shared member through an instance" and that I change it to Canvas.

Comment: And "Canvas.SetLeft(RandomTextBox, r.Next(0, Me.ActualWidth - RandomTextBox.Width))" just provokes my OOP brain. Why not RandomTextBox.SetLeft(...) or .Left = n? Anyway, I have not been able to see any Herpdiderp. I've played around with it and stopped drawing anything else, but nothing works. I've verified that the textbox is in Me.Children and that it has the right values. It just doesn't draw.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer. #WozzeC, you were right about using the canvas - almost.

I have managed to solve this in xaml alone - I want to eventually solve it in vb.net.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="DockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Menu Height="23" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Name="Menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Canvas Name="Canvas1" Background="Aquamarine">
            <TextBox Canvas.Left="118" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Canvas.Top="81" AcceptsReturn="True"  Height="auto" Name="TextBox1" Width="68" Text="Herpdiderp" BorderThickness="0" Background="Aquamarine" />
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

And here is a piece of code that expands the text as needed. I think it's almost totally cool. It expands both to the right and downwards, as if you're actually typing on the form. It adds a little too much on the right, but it's not visible in this version because the background color is the same.

Here is the event code that expands it to the right.

```
    Imports System.Globalization
Class MainWindow
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim ft As New FormattedText(TextBox1.Text, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection.LeftToRight, New Typeface("Verdana"), 16, Brushes.Black)
    TextBox1.Width = ft.Width
End Sub
End Class
```

I tried this with my existing solution and the textbox does *not* appear. I made the DrawingCanvas into a plain Canvas and commented out all the code referring to the DrawingCanvas. And the textbox *does* appear. The problem is this: I need the functionality in the DrawingCanvas - which derives from Canvas. But because the baseclass methods are Protected, I can't get to them. I can only use them in a derived class, unless there is another way I don't know about.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: This was supposed to come at the end. I wanted to show new code.